# __beginthreadex was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, sockets, dev-c++

I am new to multi threading.  I am trying to make a program that will listen to incoming connections, while being able to send data at the same time.

Here is the code so far.  It is not finished yet, because I am stuck trying to figure out why I get this error:

> __beginthreadex was not declared in this scope

Same goes for `__endthreadex`.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#pragma comment (lib,"Ws2_32.lib")

#define PORT "27015"
#define BUFLEN 512

using namespace std;

char recvbuf[BUFLEN];
int ires;
int recvbuflen=BUFLEN;

void Thread(void* data, SOCKET *x[2]) {
    listen(*x[0],128);
    *x[1]=accept(*x[0],NULL,NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    SOCKET *SOKETI[2];

    HANDLE H;
    string X="Ping.";
    string Y;

    int i;
    WSADATA wsa;

    i=WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0),&wsa);

    struct addrinfo *result=NULL, *ptr=NULL, hints;

    ZeroMemory(&hints,sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family=AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol=IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags=AI_PASSIVE;

    i=getaddrinfo(NULL,PORT,&hints,&result);

    SOCKET LSock;
    LSock=socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

    i=bind(LSock,result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);
    SOCKET CSock=INVALID_SOCKET;

    SOKETI[0]=&LSock;
    SOKETI[1]=&CSock;

    H=(HANDLE)__beginthreadx(&Thread,0,&SOKETI,0,0,0);

    while(1) {
        //RECIEVER
        i=recv(CSock,recvbuf,recvbuflen,0);
        Y.append(recvbuf, recvbuf + i);
        if (i=sizeof(X)){
            H=(HANDLE)__endthreadx(&Thread,0,&SOKETI,0,0,0);
            CloseHandle(H);
            cout<<"Recieved "<<Y<<endl;
            getchar();
            return 0;   
        }
        //RECIEVER
    }
}
```

EDIT

I realized that I misspelled the function. Other mistakes done here are another topic.

Comment: The function name is `_beginthreadex` with only a single leading underscore.  You're trying to call `__beginthreadex` with two leading underscores, and there's no such function.

Comment: The functions also end in `ex`, not just `x`. It's not clear, which functions you are really trying to call. The signatures in your question and in the code do not match. And there's no error message either.

Comment: There are other bugs in this code as well.  Not checking for errors on *any* of the function calls. Misusing `sizeof()`. Passing wrong parameters to `_endthreadex()`.  Even if all of that is fixed, this code is still a bad example of multithreading. The worker thread only does one thing - accepts one client and then terminates - and the main thread is calling `recv()` before a client has been accepted. A better example of multithreading would be to call `accept()` in a loop in the main thread and then launch a worker thread for each client that is accepted.